# @SpringBootTest does not create embedded H2, create schema, or seed db with test data with Junit5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit5, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to create a smoke test for my Spring Boot application.  I would like to setup a Junit 5 test class akin to the following so I can execute a request against the server and have it return results from H2.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CountriesIntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    @Sql("classpath:country/country-inserts.sql")
    public void shouldRetrunCountry() {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, no sql schema is create for my H2 embedded database and therefore the sql script is not ran.  And I'm not sure why this is the case.

However, if I replace the SpringBootTest annotation with `@DataJpaTest` then the schema gets created and the insert sql script gets ran.

So I'm sure there is some additional annotation I need to add to my `@SpringBootTest` but I'm not sure what it is.

I have tried adding the following annotations but none of them seemed to work:

```
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@ImportAutoConfiguration
```

And of course I cannot combine `@DataJpaTest` with `@SpringBootTest` but then how would I go about creating a full E2E test?

Comment: Did you forget the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation on your test class?

Comment: @ck1 no I do not need to add ```@RunWith(Springrunn.class)``` because I am using Junit 5.  With Junit 5 you can add ```@SpringBootTest``` and it will automatically add the ```@ExtendsWith(SpringExtension.class)```

Comment: Works for me.  Enabling debug logging via `logging.level.org.springframework.test: DEBUG` shows that the SQL script is executed against H2.  `[    Test worker] .s.t.c.j.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener : Executing SQL scripts: [class path resource [inserts.sql]]`